# How to make a button that uses a custom asset and links to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS, HTML, and JS but I hope to learn more as I progress through developing my portfolio site. Currently I am trying to put custom buttons I designed on my site, that link to another page. I have the button zero and click state working, but I'm not 100% sure how to make it so that button can be used to link to another page on my site.

Here is the code so far.

```
<html>
 <head><title>button</title>
 <style>

 div.butn{
 background-image:url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54da7941e4b0e25dc3648a4f/t/59640885b3db2b282c21c56e/1499728005971/zero_state%40300x-8.png@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700");

 width:555px;
 height:170px;}

 div.butn:active{
 background-image:url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54da7941e4b0e25dc3648a4f/t/5964090b6b8f5bf77b28504f/1499728139538/hover_state%40300x-8.png");

 width:555px;
 height:170px;}
 </style>
 </head>
<body>

<div class="butn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated, sorry in advance for any noobie mistakes xD

Comment: and this is not specific about `html` or `css`, more about `javascript`... search little bit about `onclick` and `window.open`...

Comment: Use a anchor tag and put the url you want to navigate to in the href, then as a class or inline style, add in your css. If you want a new window, use target="_blank".

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to stick with semantic HTML, i.e. use proper tags for what you are trying to convey. In your example you want a button to act like a hyperlink to another URL, so why don't you use the anchor tag which was made for exactely that purpose?

Let's see how we can improve things a bit:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>button</title>
  <style>
    .butn {
      background-image:url(.../plain.image");
      width:555px;
      height:170px;
    }

    .butn:active{
      background-image:url("../active.image");
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p><a class="butn" href="https://..." title="Show this text on hover">Go to YouTube</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what has changed besides the use of the anchor tag? Quite a lot, actually:

- I chose a proper character set (UTF-8 should be fine for most about everything)
- I lowered your CSS rule's [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (you may read up on as to why this is !important (no pun intended) on [Smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/))
- I used an anchor tag `<a>` to properly mark up the hyperlink
- I got rid off the superfluous CSS properties within the `.btn:active` rule (see [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) to learn all about how styles are cascaded)
- and last but not least, I properly aligned your code (call me pedantic but missaligned code makes it more difficult to read and hinders your thought process)

There's a lot more ground to cover but this should be enough to keep you occupied for the next two weeks. Keep asking!

Comment: thanks so much @aefxx, the link is functional now... however, the image assets I have injected into the site aren't being called on and instead I get this - https://pasteboard.co/GAOUeCY.png - it looks like the top left corner of the button asset I have created, am I simply not displaying enough of the image?

Comment: @WilliamOliver I can't really tell without knowing what it should look like. Show me your mockup and I will tell you how to do it.

Comment: here is the button style, inactive and active - https://pasteboard.co/GAVRRrK.png - I want to have the inactive state displayed and then when a user hovers over (it's click right now) the active state is displayed. Is that what you meant by mockup? All I did with the code you provided me (thanks!) was replace your plain/active buttons with the real URLs of the buttons states.

Comment: could you explain what you mean when you say mockup? Sorry to bother ya, I was having trouble with the buttons so I moved on to other aspects of the website which have been going well

Comment: No problem, the screenshot you provided actually is the mockup I asked for. I just haven't had the time to answer, yet. The code in my answer above should work for you, as long as you make sure the button's dimension match those of your background images. As for the background images: you might want to take a look at the `background-repeat` and `background-position` CSS properties for maximum control.